# Configure message retention duration of PubSub with Java client library

Tags: java, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using [google cloud pubsub java library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-pubsub) in my desktop application. I create subscription for specific topic and receive data from it. I am wondering if I can configure message retention duration of subscription. I cannot find it anywhere. Thanks.

To make the question more clear, I pasted the code block that I used to create subscription:

```
String topicName = "some-topic";
String subscriptionName = "some-subscription";
ProjectTopicName topic = ProjectTopicName.of(PROJECT_ID, topicName);
ProjectSubscriptionName subscription = ProjectSubscriptionName.of(PROJECT_ID, subscriptionName);
SubscriptionAdminClient subscriptionAdminClient = SubscriptionAdminClient.create(); // I reuse this object so I create it in advance
try {
   subscriptionAdminClient.createSubscription(subscription,
        topic,
        PushConfig.getDefaultInstance(),
        0
   );
} catch (ApiException e) {
   if (e.getStatusCode().getCode() != StatusCode.Code.ALREADY_EXISTS) {
        subscriptionAdminClient.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like there's enough information here to answer your question accurately.  Take a look at our [MCVE] guide, and edit your question to add more detail.  Show us what you tried, why it doesn't work for you, and double check that you have a specific, objective question that can be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the message retention duration of a subscription in Java. When creating a `Subscription` object, you can provide the [`message_retention_duration field`](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/create#body.request_body.FIELDS.message_retention_duration) in your creation request. To do this in Java, use [`setMessageRetentionDuration` method on `Subscription.Builder`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-grpc/0.69.0/com/google/pubsub/v1/Subscription.Builder.html#setMessageRetentionDuration-com.google.protobuf.Duration-) object, as in this example (using `com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub:1.86.0` dependency) :

```
package com.example;

import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.SubscriptionAdminClient;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.Subscription;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.TopicName;

import com.google.protobuf.util.Durations;

import java.io.IOException;

public class PubSubCreateSubscription {

    static Subscription createSubscriptionWithMessageRetentionDuration(
        String topicName,
        String subscriptionName,
        long messageRetentionDurationInMillis
    ) throws IOException {
        try (SubscriptionAdminClient subscriptionAdminClient = SubscriptionAdminClient.create()) {
            Subscription request = Subscription.newBuilder()
                .setName(subscriptionName)
                .setTopic(topicName)
                .setMessageRetentionDuration(Durations
                    .fromMillis(messageRetentionDurationInMillis))
                .build();

            return subscriptionAdminClient
                .createSubscription(request);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String topicName = "projects/[PROJECT]/topics/[TOPIC_NAME]";
        String subscriptionName = "projects/[PROJECT]/subscriptions/[SUBSCRIPTION_NAME]";

        try {
            Subscription mySubscription = createSubscriptionWithMessageRetentionDuration(
                topicName,
                subscriptionName,
                600000 // 600 000 ms = 10 minutes
            );
            // [...]
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `setMessageRetentionDuration` takes a [`Duration`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Duration) as parameter, so you might need to use [`Durations` helper class](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/util/Durations) (`fromMillis` method for example) to convert your milliseconds to a protobuf `Duration`. Note also that [from the REST resource documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/create#body.request_body.FIELDS.message_retention_duration), this field :

> Cannot be more than 7 days or less than 10 minutes.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you so much!